# Background position from top to bottom slows down as it reaches the bottom

Tags: css, ionic2, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to create a "timeout" visual effect in an Ionic 2 screen. So the background colour slides from top to bottom.

So it's like the user has a certain amount of time to click on an element in the screen and the slide moving from top to bottom is showing this.

So after searching a found a way to do this:

```
ion-content.content {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue 50%, white 50%);
  transition: background-position 30s;
}

ion-content.content.timeout {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
}
```

In the template:

```
<ion-content padding text-center [class.timeout]="isViewLoaded">
```

And in the component itself I'm doing this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  setTimeout(() => this.isViewLoaded = true, 1000);
}
```

So I add a class to ion-content around 1 sec after the view is loaded, and that triggers the transition.

This seems to work fine, but the problem is that the slide is really fast at the beginning and then starts to slow down and by the time it reaches the bottom it's really really slow.

Anyone has an idea on why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function - timing is naturally as a `ease` function which speeds up and then slows down, you seem to be wanting `linear` timing instread..

Comment: the thing is not that I want a 1s delay; if I don´t add the class that way when the view is loaded .timeout is already added and the background position is already `0 -100%` so there's no transition, the background is already white.

Comment: fair enough. I mistook your code for jS but it's `ionic2` which I don' know so.....

Comment: no problem, @Martin I'm happy to accept your answer as valid if you want; I used `transition-timing-function: linear;` and it worked perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) - timing is naturally as a ease function which speeds up and then slows down, you seem to be wanting linear timing instread.

If you read up on MDN about `transition-timing` it will state:

> Initial value:    **ease**

`ease` speeds up from the outset and then slows down towards the end, rather like a bell curve of speed over time. This is why your item is slowing down and seemingly taking a long time to finally reach its destination.

See Graph from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3434/TF_with_output_gt_than_1.png

On this page:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#CSS_properties_used_to_define_transitions

A solution to this is to edit your CSS and use the `linear` method which does not speed up or slow down but transitions at a constant speed.

```
ion-content.content {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue 50%, white 50%);
  transition: background-position 30s linear;
                                      ^^^^^^
}
```

Clarifying the change:

```
ion-content.content {
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue 50%, white 50%);
  transition: background-position 30s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```